# GroupBox not animating on picker's selection change

Tags: animation, swiftui, picker, groupbox

I have a picker view inside a groupbox. When changing the selected value inside the picker the size of the picker's label changes and the groupbox's width too. I added an animation on the groupbox with the picker's selection value as a value to monitor for changes. But the groupbox does not animate

```
GroupBox {
             
                    Picker("Period", selection: $periodIndex) {
                        ForEach(0..<periods.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            Text(periods[index]).tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .tint(.white)   
       
        }
        .animation(.spring, value: periodIndex)
```

Since I never animated using an integer I used a boolean that toggles when the picker's selection value changes but it didn't work too

Comment: You should almost never use indices with `ForEach`. Switch to `Identifiable` data.

Comment: Could you give a reason pls ? @jnpdx

Comment: watch "Demystifying SwiftUI" from WWDC. Using indices breaks identity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the lack of animation has anything to do with the `GroupBox`. This is just the way a native `Picker` works when the picker style is `.menu`. But you notice it a bit more here because the `GroupBox` adds a background shape which is changing in size when the selection changes.

I couldn't find a way to animate the change. But you can at least avoid a change of group size by applying a `minWidth` to the `Picker`. Something like:

```swift
Picker("Period", selection: $periodIndex) {
    // content as before
}
.frame(minWidth: 100)
```

The selection itself still changes without animation, but at least the `GroupBox` does not change size.

Ps. you can edit your own post to fix the erroneous `value` on the `.animation` modifier.

---

*EDIT* I tried it with the string array you gave in a comment. A `minWidth` of **110** stops the size from changing for me and I don't see any wrapping issue.

```swift
private let periods = ["Fajr", "Sunrise", "Dhuhr", "Asr", "Maghrib", "Isha", "Midnight"]
@State private var periodIndex = 0

var body: some View {
    GroupBox {
        Picker("Period", selection: $periodIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<periods.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(periods[index])
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .tint(.white)
        .frame(minWidth: 110)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: but then the picker's label renders on multiple lines somehow

Comment: @DanyJamous Are you sure you set `minWidth` and not `width`? It worked for me. Just make sure the `minWidth` is wide enough for your widest label.

Comment: It's not happening with the widest label but with the shortest one..

Comment: @DanyJamous Do the labels have any strange characters in them, such as newline? Do you still see the problem when you omit the option with the shortest label? I can't reproduce any wrapping problem so suspect it must be due to the characters in the label.

Comment: Here is the text array : ["Fajr", "Sunrise", "Dhuhr", "Asr", "Maghrib", "Isha", "Midnight"] I have a problem with index 4 and 5

Comment: @DanyJamous Answer updated to show how it works for me.

Comment: I actually have the picker in a HStack, among the elements is a text. When removed it actually works so I set a width for the text and it worked as well. I'll wait to mark your answer as the solution in case someone can animate the groupbox